# Include local gem in Rack app

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

I'm creating a rack app gem. I include my gem locallly in my gem file but I can't include it in my `config.ru` file.

novo.gemspec

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'novo/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  gem.name          = "novo"
  gem.version       = Novo::VERSION
  gem.authors       = ["Tobias Sandelius"]
  gem.email         = ["tobias@sandeli.us"]
  gem.description   = %q{TODO: Write a gem description}
  gem.summary       = %q{TODO: Write a gem summary}
  gem.homepage      = ""

  gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  gem.test_files    = gem.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
end
```

config.ru

```
require 'novo'

# Set site root
NOVO_ROOT = Dir.pwd

run Novo::Dispatcher.new
```

I get the following error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- novo (LoadError)
```

I'm missing something but don't know what?

Comment: Did you create the whole gem with `bundle new`? However, can you show your Gemfile?

Comment: No I just use it locally. I don't want to build the gem everytime I update it. I include it with the path: '~/foo/bar' argument.